# How to do format expression in ssis expression language

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sqldatatypes, dts

In sql we have got data type format like

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CONVERT(DATETIME, [ReferralDate], 0), 108)
```

Is there any way to achieve the same using ssis expression language?

yes we can convert to string or any other required data types using the expression similar to

```
(DT_STR, 10,1252)dob
```

But my question is how to get the required format by passing the number values such as **108(as mentioned in the above sql) or 123/106 etc**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no analog in the Expression language for locale formatting. You'd need to use a Script Task or Component to apply formatting. [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

That said, your first example seems to be extracting the hours and minutes from a date in `hh:mm` format while I assume the other is going to be converting a date in a string using whatever your locale specifies.

## STOP STORING DATES AND TIMES IN STRING DATA TYPES!

The data types of date, datetime, time, etc store the values in a local agnostic mechanism. That means you don't have to worry about whether a string value of "01-02-05" is  "Feb  1 2005" -> en-GB, "Jan  2 2005" -> en-US or "Feb  5 2001" -> ja-JP. Instead, these are *presentation* concepts that have no business being in your database.